# Janusgraph - How to hide the edge relation between two vertices and establish / retrieve again based on a condition?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I'm new to the Janusgraph Database. I have a requirement where I need to hide the relation (edge) between two vertices without dropping them and later I should able retrieve / establish the same relation again between those vertices based on condition.

I only know how to drop the edges but I don't know how to retrieve/restore the relation again. Could you please help me out here.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to 'restore' the connections I think you shouldn't drop them at all.

Just keep a property on the edge that indicates the edge state (active/inactive) or maybe keep a start and end date on the edge.
This way when you traverse your graph you need to makes sure to use only the active edges, but the old ones can still easily found if you want to restore them.

for example:

```
g.addV('person').property('id', 'bob').property('name', 'Bob')
g.addV('person').property('id', 'alice').property('name', 'Alice')
g.addV('person').property('id', 'eve').property('name', 'Eve')
g.V('bob').addE('friend').to(g.V('alice'))
g.V('bob').addE('friend').to(g.V('eve'))
```

So Bob friends with Alice and Eve:

```
g.V('bob').out('friend').values("name")
==>Alice
==>Eve
```

Let say Bob and Alice had a fallout, and they are no longer friends:

```
g.V('bob').outE('friend').where(inV().hasId('alice')).property('status', 'inactive')
```

now you can query only Bob active friends, without dropping the old edges:

```
g.V('bob').outE('friend').not(has('status', 'inactive')).inV().values("name")
==> Eve
```

Comment: I agree with this approach. I would use the enabled/disabled flag personally because then you can index it and more easily ignore disabled edges.